# Метод для определения количества слов из четырех букв в строке

Tags: java

Нужно написать метод, который принимает строку и возвращает количество имен из 4-х букв. Не получается String преобразовать в Integer и посчитать слова.

```
public static int fourLetters(String name) {
        String[] str = name.split(" ");
        int res = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int in = Integer.parseInt(Arrays.toString(str));
        for (int i = 0; i < in; i++) {
            if (in <= 4) {
                res += count++;
            }

        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(fourLetters("Dina Fernanfo Huan Dicsperro Dana Rodriges"));

    }
```

Comment: Что должно оказаться в переменной `in`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Four {

    public static int FourString(String str) {
        int count = 0;
        String[] name = str.split(" ");
        int lon = name.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < lon; i++) {
            String num = name[i];

            if (num.length() == 4) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Dina Fernando Huan Dicsperro Dana Rodriges ";
        System.out.println(FourString(str));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static int fourLetters(String name) {
        String[] str = name.split(" ");
        int count = 0;
        for (String token : str) {
            if (token.length() == 4) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(fourLetters("Dina Fernanfo Huan Dicsperro Dana Rodriges"));
    }
```